# Grid and label in a coordinate with a different angle betwenn the axis

Tags: coordinates, angle, tikz-angles

I have drawn a coordinate with an angle of 30 degrees betwenn the x- and the y- axis like this:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\xangle}{30}
\newcommand{\yangle}{60}
\newcommand{\zangle}{45}

\newcommand{\xlength}{1}
\newcommand{\ylength}{1.7}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{\xlength*cos(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xy}{\xlength*sin(\xangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yx}{\ylength*cos(\yangle)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\ylength*sin(\yangle)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   x={(\xx cm,\xy cm)},
    y={(\yx cm,\yy cm)},
%    z={(\zx cm,\zy cm)},
]
\draw[-latex,red] (-1,0,0) -- (3.5,0,0) node[label=\xangle:x] {};
\draw[-latex,blue] (0,-1,0) -- (0,3.5,0) node[label=\yangle:y] {};
%\draw[-latex,black] (0,0,-1) -- (0,0,3.5) node[label=\zangle:z] {};

\foreach \c in {0,...,3}
{   \fill[red] (\c,0,0) circle (0.05cm);
    \fill[blue] (0,\c,0) circle (0.05cm);
%    \fill[black] (0,0,\c) circle (0.05cm);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It is a modified example from [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66036/setting-coordinate-system-for-tikz-picture).

My question is now, how to assimilate the grid on the new constructed axis. If I use the grid option, the grid is plotted as in a normal cartesian system and is not assimilated to the changed degree.